# How do I create a view with a 'Content pane' display type?

Tags: 7, views

I would like to create a new view that that I can use as a Content (panel) Pane. I cannot find how to do this. Would anyone know?

Comment: Do you have the appropriate ctools sub-module, views_content module, enabled? That module provides this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it.

I was looking for the option on the first screen where you give the view a name and select if it's a block or not. Instead you must add a new Display instead, on the 2nd screen, and select it from the drop down list that appears